# Delay permanent deletion from google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to ensure deleted files have a window of recovery.  I'd like to use the primitives offered by google cloud storage such that I don't have to maintain the logic necessary to prevent files deleted in error from being irrecoverable.

I do not see a better way to achieve than doing:

1. create `normal` bucket for files that are displayed to the users
2. create `trash` bucket for files pending permanent deletion with [lifecycle rule](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#conditions) that deletes objects after N days of creation
3. upon file deletion request from the `normal` bucket, first copy files to the `trash` bucket , then deletion of file from `normal` bucket

What is the "idiomatic" way of implementing delayed permanent deletion GCP cloud storage?

*NOTE: I am trying to avoid chron jobs or additional database interaction*

*NOTE: this is not a soft delete as the file is expected to eventually be permanently deleted without any trace/storage associated with it*

Comment: no answers and a downvote...is there anything I could do to improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep all the files in the same bucket like this, assuming two things:

1. Each file is also referenced in a database that you're querying to build the UI.
2. You're able to write backend code to manage the bucket - peoeple are not dealing with files directly with a Cloud Storage SDK.

It uses Cloud Tasks to schedule the deletion:

1. User asks for file deletion.
2. File is marked as "deleted" in the database, not actually deleted from bucket.
3. Use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) to schedule the actual deletion 5 days from now.
4. On schedule, the task triggers a function, which deletes the file and its database record.

Your UI will have to query the database in order to differentiate between deleted and trashed files.

Comment: many thanks @Doug Stevenson for approaching this question. I am trying to avoid another separate database if possible.  That said if this is the "idiomatic" way of achieving this functionality in Google Cloud Storage then I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  I'm very new to GCP in general. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Since Cloud Storage doesn't have a way to make flexible queries against its contents, many people choose to augment it with a database to make it easier to find files with certain properties.  I don't know if that's considered "idiomatic", but it's common and necessary for many use cases.  You should use the solution that best meets your individual needs.

Comment: the amount of objects I'll be storing in the `normal` bucket I'm referring to is minimal so I won't have a need for more than simple listing of the contents from a `gsutil ls gs://<bucket-name>`.  That said may be I am approaching this wrong for other reasons.  Again, thank you for sharing your experience!